# function treats arguments as strings not integers

Tags: python, string, function, integer, args

I'm new to python and was having some issues with a function that I had defined. I had decided to use *numbers (*args) in my function so that my function could take any amount of arguments. However, in using *numbers when defining my function, it seems that my arguments are treated as a string rather than an integer. As you can see below, I receive the output 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 when inputting the argument "4".
The output that I was looking for was actually 32 however I can't seem to get this output as I can't get my arguments to be treated like an integer. I have tried including int(numbers) to my function but to no avail. Are there any slight changes I can make to get my desired output?

```
def multiply_machine(*numbers):
    multiplied_number=3*numbers
    m_numbers=5*numbers
    return multiplied_number + m_numbers

print(multiply_machine(4))

OUT[1] : (4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4)
```

Comment: " it seems that my arguments are treated as a string rather than an integer." no, no it isn't. There are no strings being shown anywhere. What is happening is that `*args` provides the variadically applied arguments as a `tuple`. How else did you expect it to work? What did you think `numbers` would be if you did `multiply_machine(1, 2)`?

Comment: So to ge the output you want, just use `def multiply_machine(numbers)`...

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response, I understand I can get the output I want if I don't use *args and simply use "def multiply_machine(numbers)". However, that limits my function to only taking one argument.  Is there a way that I can slightly adjust my initial function so that I can do print(multiply_machine(4,2,1)) and get the outputs 32,16,8

Comment: Sure, again, *the arguments will be provided as a `tuple`*. So `type(args) is tuple`, and if you do `multiply_machine(4,2,1)` then `args == (4, 2, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

The input is understood as a tuple.

```
print(multiply_machine(4))

def multiply_machine(numbers=(4,)):
    multiplied_number=3*(4,)
    m_numbers=5*(4,)
    return (4, 4, 4) + (4, 4, 4, 4, 4)
```

Thus, to have expected results, you should work with it as with a tuple. What was your intention to actually achieve is not clear to me. You might want to edit your question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of '**iter**' attribute provided by the '*numbers'

Option 1

```
def multiply_machine(*numbers): # preferable use args
    print(hasattr(numbers, '__iter__'))
multiply_machine(4,3,4,4,5)
```

Output

```
True
```

so you can iterate through

```
def multiply_machine(*numbers): # preferable use args
    multiplied_number = [3 * x for x in numbers]
    m_numbers = [5 * x for x in numbers]
    summed = [x + y for x, y in zip(multiplied_number,m_numbers)]
    return summed
print(multiply_machine(4))
print(multiply_machine(4,2,1))
```

Output: Note it returns as

```
[32]
[32, 16, 8]
```

Option 2:
You can convert your function into a generator like so:

```
def multiply_machine(*numbers): # preferable use args
    yield from numbers


for i in multiply_machine(4,2,3,4,5):
    summed  = (5*i) + (3*i)
    print(summed, end=' ')
```

Output

```
32 16 24 32 40
```